# Cannot connect to pop3 or imap with Dovecot

Tags: email, imap, postfix, pop3, dovecot

Connections are refused on my server. Note: I am trying to connect from localhost here.

Command I'm trying to use to test:

```
user@hostname:~$ telnet localhost pop3
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Same error when I try with imap.

The [dovecot wiki](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/TestPop3Installation) suggests trouble shooting for the issue, however I have already tried the fixes. I have the protocols added in the config, and I have the listen option set to `*`. My config is below. I am not sure what is wrong?
    ## Dovecot configuration file

```
# If you're in a hurry, see http://wiki2.dovecot.org/QuickConfiguration

# "doveconf -n" command gives a clean output of the changed settings. Use it
# instead of copy&pasting files when posting to the Dovecot mailing list.

# '#' character and everything after it is treated as comments. Extra spaces
# and tabs are ignored. If you want to use either of these explicitly, put the
# value inside quotes, eg.: key = "# char and trailing whitespace  "

# Default values are shown for each setting, it's not required to uncomment
# those. These are exceptions to this though: No sections (e.g. namespace {})
# or plugin settings are added by default, they're listed only as examples.
# Paths are also just examples with the real defaults being based on configure
# options. The paths listed here are for configure --prefix=/usr
# --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var

# Enable installed protocols
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol
protocols = pop3 pop3s imap imaps
pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv

# A comma separated list of IPs or hosts where to listen in for connections.
# "*" listens in all IPv4 interfaces, "::" listens in all IPv6 interfaces.
# If you want to specify non-default ports or anything more complex,
# edit conf.d/master.conf.
#listen = *, ::

# Base directory where to store runtime data.
#base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/

# Name of this instance. Used to prefix all Dovecot processes in ps output.
#instance_name = dovecot

# Greeting message for clients.
#login_greeting = Dovecot ready.

# Space separated list of trusted network ranges. Connections from these
# IPs are allowed to override their IP addresses and ports (for logging and
# for authentication checks). disable_plaintext_auth is also ignored for
# these networks. Typically you'd specify your IMAP proxy servers here.
#login_trusted_networks =

# Sepace separated list of login access check sockets (e.g. tcpwrap)
#login_access_sockets =

# Show more verbose process titles (in ps). Currently shows user name and
# IP address. Useful for seeing who are actually using the IMAP processes
# (eg. shared mailboxes or if same uid is used for multiple accounts).
#verbose_proctitle = no

# Should all processes be killed when Dovecot master process shuts down.
# Setting this to "no" means that Dovecot can be upgraded without
# forcing existing client connections to close (although that could also be
# a problem if the upgrade is e.g. because of a security fix).
#shutdown_clients = yes

# If non-zero, run mail commands via this many connections to doveadm server,
# instead of running them directly in the same process.
#doveadm_worker_count = 0
# UNIX socket or host:port used for connecting to doveadm server
#doveadm_socket_path = doveadm-server

# Space separated list of environment variables that are preserved on Dovecot
# startup and passed down to all of its child processes. You can also give
# key=value pairs to always set specific settings.
#import_environment = TZ

##
## Dictionary server settings
##

# Dictionary can be used to store key=value lists. This is used by several
# plugins. The dictionary can be accessed either directly or though a
# dictionary server. The following dict block maps dictionary names to URIs
# when the server is used. These can then be referenced using URIs in format
# "proxy::<name>".
```

Comment: Have you tried using the port numbers instead of the service name when testing via telnet?

Comment: @ernie I tried using the port 110 and same problem.

Comment: All right, and to ask the obvious, you started the daemon and verified it was running?

Comment: @ernie Yep `ps -A | grep dovecot` reports that it is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't define appropriate listeners for protocols.
Try to begin from the single-file config like that:

```
## Dovecot configuration file

mail_location           = maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n
protocols               = imap pop3
listen                  = *

mail_uid                = mailnull
mail_gid                = mail
first_valid_uid         = 26
first_valid_gid         = 6
last_valid_uid          = 0
last_valid_gid          = 0

log_path                = syslog
syslog_facility         = mail
auth_mechanisms         = plain
auth_socket_path        = /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb

mail_plugin_dir         = /usr/local/lib/dovecot
postmaster_address      = postmaster@%d
hostname                = %d
sendmail_path           = /usr/local/sbin/exim
lda_mailbox_autocreate  = yes
lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes

passdb {
  driver        = sql
  args          = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.sql
}

userdb {
  driver        = sql
  args          = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.sql
}

protocol lda {
}

protocol pop3 {
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}

protocol imap {
  mail_plugins          = quota imap_quota antispam
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail tb-extra-mailbox-sep tb-lsub-flags
}
## - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode        = 0600
    user        = $mail_uid
    group       = $mail_gid
  }
}

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port        = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port        = 993
    ssl         = yes
  }
}

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port        = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port        = 995
    ssl         = yes
  }
}
####
```